# Get values inside controller during post (radiobutton tied to a keyvalue pair)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Could you please help me on this?

Inside controller i am setting the model as follows:

```
model.Question1 = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(questions[0].Id, questions[0].Question);            
model.Question2 = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(questions[1].Id, questions[1].Question);
model.Question3 = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(questions[2].Id, questions[2].Question);
model.Question4 = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(questions[3].Id, questions[3].Question);

return View(model);
```

Inside my view here is what i have:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Question1.Value, true, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })<text>Yes</text>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Question1.Value, false, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })<text>No</text>
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Question1.Value)<br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the page posts back during a button click, i would like to get the values of radio button clicked. 
How could i achieve that?

Comment: Your model makes no sense. Your binding to a the Value which is `int` but your radio buttons are `true` and `false` - i.e. bind to a `bool`, not an int, and you never bind anything to the Key so nothing could bind anyway.

Comment: And your `ValidationMessageFor()` makes less sense - its a `KeyValuePair` and does not have any validation, and you not (and cannot ) create a form control for `KeyValuePair` anyway.

Comment: I fixed by changing it to bool.